# How to profile RSpec with perftools and bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, profiling, google-perftools

I need to profile the test suite that I usually run with `bundle exec rspec spec/` and produce the GIF image.

What is the command to run the [perftools.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/perftools.rb) so that it works correctly with bundler?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I too had to dig around to get this. Here is what I did

1. Put this in spec_helper.rb:

   ```
   config.before :suite do
     PerfTools::CpuProfiler.start("/tmp/rspec_profile")
   end

   config.after :suite do
     PerfTools::CpuProfiler.stop
   end
   ```
2. Run your rspec
3. Run pprof to get your numbers

   ```
   pprof.rb --text  /tmp/rspec_profile
   ```

Comment: you can also do --gif but it would require you to have graphviz installed. run pprof.rb to get all available options

Comment: also given the original requirement of bundler... you may have to bundle exec pprof.rb --text /tmp/rspec_profile